# BUG - rotation of Default image on iOS with AIR SDK 16.0.0.250

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I just switched to AIR SDK 16.0.0.250. Everything was fine except one very strange problem with Default images on iOS devices.

My app runs in landscape mode. In my app I have default images that are shown during application loading phase.

When app start, first I see Default image properly, that for a very short period of time I see Default image rotated 90 degree and scaled to fill the screen and then it disappears and application is get loaded.

Here is a video that illustrates the problem: http://youtu.be/Ry1l1v7dQss

That is very strange, so I want to know if anybody else knows how to handle this issue and what could the source of it?

Some info that might help:

Application descriptor:

```
<initialWindow>
    <content>SWF file name is set automatically at compile time</content>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
    <softKeyboardBehavior>none</softKeyboardBehavior>
</initialWindow>
```

List of default images:

- Default.png
- Default@2x.png
- Default-568h@2x.png
- Default-Landscape.png
- Default-LandscapeLeft@2x.png

p.s.: One of my thoughts was that app somehow uses not one, but few images during loading phase so I did remove all but Default-LandscapeLeft@2x.png and tested on iPad - no positive results.

So, for me it seems like a bug in AIR SDK 16.0.0.250

Answer (score 0):

Try only including the Default-Landscape.png.

Comment: Bah. After testing this out it does seem to be an AIR bug. 16.0.0.222 was working correctly but later versions (including 16.0.0.259 are displaying the bug. I've created a bug report which you can vote up. https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3917402